# Magento: How to display recurring profile information for a configurable recurring product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, recurring-billing

I've created a configurable product that will allow the user to choose between a recurring and non-recurring version of a product (each version being a simple product). The problem I'm having is that when the user selects the recurring option, they aren't presented with the recurring profile information that they would see for a simple recurring product. How can I get Magento to display this information conditionally for a configurable product?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working solution, arrived at through some lucky guesses.

```
// check to see if the product is configurable
if ( $_product->getTypeID() == 'configurable' ) {
    // get the associated products    
    $associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
    // iterate through the products, checking for recurring products
    foreach ( $associatedProducts as $associatedProduct ) {
        if ($associatedProduct->isRecurring()) {
            // get the recurring profile
            $profile = $associatedProduct->getRecurringProfile();
            // echo whichever array members you need
            echo '<p>billed '.$profile['period_frequency'].' time(s) per '.$profile['period_unit'].'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

I got some help here: http://www.phptechi.com/how-to-get-associated-child-product.html

Then I just made a lucky method-name guess for `getRecurringProfile()`.

`var_dump($associatedProduct->getRecurrringProfile())` yields:

```
array(13) { 
["start_date_is_editable"]=> string(1) "1" 
["schedule_description"]=> string(0) "" 
["suspension_threshold"]=> string(0) "" 
["bill_failed_later"]=> string(1) "1" ["period_unit"]=> string(5) "month"        
["period_frequency"]=> string(1) "1" ["period_max_cycles"]=> string(0) "" 
["trial_period_unit"]=> string(0) "" ["trial_period_frequency"]=> string(0) "" 
["trial_period_max_cycles"]=> string(0) "" ["trial_billing_amount"]=> string(0) "" 
["init_amount"]=> string(0) "" ["init_may_fail"]=> string(1) "0" 
}
```